# Javascript - Using window.open() with Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, basic-authentication

When the user logs into my app, he can click on a button to download a CSV file from the server. This URL for the download is protected using basic authentication. When I do this :

```
window.open('http://url-of-the-csv-file');
```

The browser shows a username/password popup (Basic Authentication)

I want to be able to open the URL without asking the user to enter his password a second time. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know basicAuth credentials of your looged-in user, you could fill in them in the URL:

```
https://user:password@url-of-the-csv-file
```

If your app is in open web, do it **ONLY if the target is on HTTPS**, because such request including credentials will be readable for anyone eavesdropping your wires. This also applies to the other (javascript) answer.